# generated images and masks in data generator of keras dont match

Tags: keras

Using data generator in Keras, I try to write the augmented image and masks on the disk. I'm doing the following but the generated augmented masks don't match the generated augmented images:

```python
image_datagen.fit(images, augment=True, seed=seed) mask_datagen.fit(masks, augment=True, seed=seed)

image_gen=image_datagen.flow(images, batch_size=1,shuffle=False, save_to_dir=dir_image, save_prefix='aug',save_format='png')

mask_gen=image_datagen.flow(masks, batch_size=1,shuffle=False, save_to_dir=dir_mask, save_prefix='aug',save_format='png')

i = 0 
for batch in zip(image_gen, mask_gen):
    i += 1 
    if i > 10: break
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem to my question my self. I should have used the same seed :
image_gen=image_datagen.flow(images,seed=seed, batch_size=1,shuffle=False, save_to_dir=dir_image, save_prefix='aug',save_format='png')

mask_gen=image_datagen.flow(masks,seed=seed, batch_size=1,shuffle=False, save_to_dir=dir_mask, save_prefix='aug',save_format='png')